# JavaFx dialog to come on top of the already opened dialog

Tags: javafx, dialog

In JavaFX, I have two dialogs which are opening one after the another whose parents are same. How to make sure that the second dialog comes on top of the first dialog and not go behind the first one.

I have tried [How do I set an Alert to be always on top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461064/how-do-i-set-an-alert-to-be-always-on-top) but this keeps the dialog always on top even if I switch to some other application.

Comment: Where is your code? We can't see what you have tried. Have you tried setting the `secondDialog.initOwner(firstDialog);`? I don't know if it's plausible.

Comment: @SedJ601 `initOwner` expects a `Window`, so that won't work directly. However, using `firstDialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow()` worked for me on Windows 10, though I had to ensure the first dialog was fully displayed before showing the second dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the use-case and I am not sure what I am missing. Because for me the second one appears always on top of first one, irrespective of whether I set the owner for the Alerts.

Can you provide additional details to reproduce your issue.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MultipleAlertsDemo extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox root = new VBox(100);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Button button = new Button("Alert");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            Alert a1 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.NONE);
            //a1.initOwner(button.getScene().getWindow());
            a1.setTitle("Alert 1");
            a1.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow().setOnCloseRequest(e -> a1.hide());
            a1.show();


            Alert a2 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.NONE);
            //a2.initOwner(button.getScene().getWindow());
            a2.setTitle("Alert 2");
            a2.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow().setOnCloseRequest(e -> a2.hide());
            a2.show();
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(button);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 250, 100));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Alerts Demo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

After checking further, It looks like the default Modality of the Alert is of type `APPLICATION_MODAL`, which is the reason why I can't access the first Alert window.

After changing the modality to `WINDOW_MODAL` and setting the main stage as owner for both Alerts, now I can see your use-case.

At this stage, there is no feature in JavaFX to maintain the z-index of Windows. The window that is focused will always be on top. To some extent we can use this feature and get the desired results.

The general idea is, every time an Alert get focused, we reorder the Windows/Alerts by requesting focus in that order. This technique will reorder the alerts by focusing one after another.

But there is a little drawback with this approach. As we are immediately turning off the focus from first Alert, we cannot perform events on the first Alert ( like closing, clicking button.. etc on alert1). We can still move the first Alert.

Below is the updated demo with the above technique:

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MultipleAlertsDemo extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox root = new VBox(100);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        List<Window> alerts = new ArrayList<>();
        Button button = new Button("Alert");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            Window parentWindow =button.getScene().getWindow();

            Alert a1 = buildAlert("Alert 1", parentWindow);
            alerts.add(a1.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow());
            a1.show();


            Alert a2 = buildAlert("Alert 2", parentWindow);
            alerts.add(a2.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow());
            a2.show();

            InvalidationListener focusListener = p -> {
                // Re-order the focus of all alerts to always keep in the alerts in same order.
                for (final Window alertWindow : alerts) {
                    alertWindow.requestFocus();
                }
            };

            for (final Window alertWindow : alerts) {
                alertWindow.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
                    alertWindow.hide();
                    alerts.remove(alertWindow);
                });

                // Add focus listener to all alerts
                alertWindow.focusedProperty().addListener(focusListener);
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(button);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 250, 100));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Alerts Demo");
        primaryStage.requestFocus();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Alert buildAlert(String title, Window parentWindow){
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.NONE);
        alert.initOwner(parentWindow);
        alert.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        alert.setTitle(title);

        Button button = new Button("Btn "+title);
        button.setOnAction(e-> System.out.println("Button clicked in "+title));
        StackPane content = new StackPane(button);
        alert.getDialogPane().setContent(content);
        return alert;
    }
}
```